# Eclipse ADT crash when autocomplete popup

Tags: java, android, eclipse, autocomplete, adt

I am using the eclipse ADT-bundle that Google lets you download directly from their site. I am in Ubuntu 13.10 and is using Oracle Java 7. My problem is that Eclipse crashes (freezes) as soon as the autocomplete popup is shown. It seems to be a reported bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=377367 but I cannot find any solution to my problem. Right now I can't develop at all. Anyone who solved this problem?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Solved it. Found out that you can add -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla to the end of your eclipse.ini file. Note that this not will work when using the OpenJDK.

Comment: Can you link to where you found the solution? Or if you know why it's happening that'll be great too :)