# Eclipse in adt-bundle for android development freezes by auto complete

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu-12.04, adt

To develop android app I downloaded the adt-bundle from the following location: dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20131030.zip
I downloaded that bundle since I have been using ubuntu 12.04.3lts(32 bit).

I have been enjoying the eclipse IDE given with the bundle(for almost 2months) but suddenly I am facing a serious error which literally stopped my development. The problem is eclipse auto complete(or code suggestion) is just freezing the window. But the mouse is ok, it allows to move the mouse as usual but keyboard and other application/process just freezes.

Though the keyboard freezes but if I press Ctrl + Alt + Fx keys then it opens command window mode. From this command window I can kill eclipse and other processes and can back to the previous window by pressing Ctrl + Alt + F7. But I can not choose other processes though. The only solution is shutdown by pressing the power key or reboot from that command window.

I've searched for almost three days of solution of this problem but nothing solved my problems. I've found similar problem in stackoverflow but the given solution didn't worked for me.

Here I am giving some links of given solution which I followed.

[Eclipse ADT Bundle crashes suddenly on Mint 16 Petra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21634846/eclipse-adt-bundle-crashes-suddenly-on-mint-16-petra)

[Eclipse continue crashing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20203771/eclipse-continue-crash)

[Eclipse ADT crash when autocomplete popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20733572/eclipse-adt-crash-when-autocomplete-popup/22353909#22353909)

Another mysterious thing is this problem sometimes gone. Sometimes I can work for 2 or 3 hours without any problem even the auto suggestion works well. But when the problem arise it just stops my that day development. On the next day eclipse may work well for 2/3 hours without any trouble.

Here I should mention that I've tried with OpenJdk6, OpenJDK7 and Oracle-java-7. I have also tried by updating my ubuntu kernel from 12.04lts to 12.04.3lts. And also tried by changing memory limit in eclipse.ini file. I've also tried by replacing the eclipse from adt-bundle with a new one from latest download.

Alas! Nothing works!

Here I am mentioning my current java version, ubuntu version and eclipse.ini files configuration:

mushfique@mushfique:~$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)

mushfique@mushfique:~$ javac -version
javac 1.7.0_51

mushfique@mushfique:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise

My hardware configuration is:
Processor: Intel® Core™ i3 CPU M 330 @ 2.13GHz × 4 
Memory: 2.8GB(Actually 3GB)
Os: 32 bit

I am also giving the complete content of my eclipse.ini file here:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-product
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
-showsplash
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-Declipse.buildId=v22.3.0-887826
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath=/usr/lib/xulrunner/
```

Sorry for my large question.

I would be grateful for any suggestion.

Thanks

Comment: Even I've tried by replacing the eclipse given with adt-bundle by eclipse-kepler standard version. No works! Same issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and I solved by adding this line

```
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
```

to the end of the eclipse.ini file.
I found the solution here:
[Eclipse ADT crash when autocomplete popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20733572/eclipse-adt-crash-when-autocomplete-popup)

Comment: That didn't worked for me. Though thanks for your answer.