# eclipse crashes all the time after running

Tags: java, android, eclipse

My eclipse with opened project crashes all the time just after running it. (Lately I've installed a new version). I have impression that it's related with lack of memory but not sure. Could you look shortly on my log and recommend me something (I cut the parts which seems to be less important because of message limit here)? (I used Eclipse for Android programming).

Additional info: Eclipse Build: v22.3.0-887826 java 7 u 51  sdk adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030

```
     #
    # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
    #
    #  Internal Error (0xeedfade), pid=5884, tid=1840
    #
    # JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_51-b13) (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
    # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (24.51-b03 mixed mode windows-x86 )
    # Problematic frame:
    # C  [KERNELBASE.dll+0x812f]
    [error occurred during error reporting (printing problematic frame), id 0xeedfade]

    # Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
    #
    # If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
    #   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
    # The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
    # See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
    #

    ---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

    Current thread (0x01b2c000):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=1840, stack(0x00030000,0x00130000)]

    siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xeedfade, ExceptionInformation=0x62004ea3 0x0123042c 0x62004ea3 0x62004ea3 0x00000000 0x0012ecbc 0x0012e82c 

(...)    

    Stack: [0x00030000,0x00130000],  sp=0x0012e7a8,  free space=1017k
    Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
    C  [KERNELBASE.dll+0x812f]
    [error occurred during error reporting (printing native stack), id 0xeedfade]

    Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
    j  org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CoCreateInstance([BII[B[I)I+0
    j  org.eclipse.swt.graphics.TextLayout.<init>(Lorg/eclipse/swt/graphics/Device;)V+96
    j  org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledTextRenderer.setFont(Lorg/eclipse/swt/graphics/Font;I)V+8
    j  org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText.<init>(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Composite;I)V+356
    j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.DefaultDetailsArea.createArea(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Composite;)Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Composite;+45
    j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.DefaultDetailsArea.createSupportArea(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Composite;Lorg/eclipse/ui/statushandlers/StatusAdapter;)Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Control;+2
    j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.DetailsAreaManager.createDetailsArea(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Composite;Lorg/eclipse/ui/statushandlers/StatusAdapter;)V+41
    j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.InternalDialog.toggleDetailsArea()Z+56
    j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.InternalDialog.buttonPressed(I)V+51
    j  org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Lorg/eclipse/swt/events/SelectionEvent;)V+17
    J  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Event;)V
    J  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Event;)V
    j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Event;)V+25
    j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents()Z+92
    j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch()Z+69
    j  org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.WorkbenchErrorHandler.showStatusAdapter(Lorg/eclipse/ui/statushandlers/StatusAdapter;Z)V+34
    j  org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.WorkbenchErrorHandler.access$0(Lorg/eclipse/ui/statushandlers/WorkbenchErrorHandler;Lorg/eclipse/ui/statushandlers/StatusAdapter;Z)V+3
    j  org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.WorkbenchErrorHandler$1.run()V+9
    j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.UILockListener.doPendingWork()V+27
    j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer$3.run()V+7
    j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run()V+11
    j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Z)Z+29
    j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Z)Z+5
    j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch()Z+91
    j  org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run()V+606
    j  org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Lorg/eclipse/core/databinding/observable/Realm;Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V+12
    j  org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(Lorg/eclipse/e4/ui/model/application/MApplicationElement;Lorg/eclipse/e4/core/contexts/IEclipseContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+57
    j  org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(Lorg/eclipse/e4/ui/model/application/MApplicationElement;)V+20
    j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run()V+256
    j  org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Lorg/eclipse/core/databinding/observable/Realm;Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V+12
    j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display;Lorg/eclipse/ui/application/WorkbenchAdvisor;)I+18
    j  org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display;Lorg/eclipse/ui/application/WorkbenchAdvisor;)I+2
    j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(Lorg/eclipse/equinox/app/IApplicationContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+108
    j  org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+135
    j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+103
    j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+29
    j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+149
    j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run([Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Runnable;)Ljava/lang/Object;+183
    v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
    j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0
    j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+87
    j  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+6
    j  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+57
    j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework([Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/net/URL;)V+211
    j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun([Ljava/lang/String;)V+126
    j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run([Ljava/lang/String;)I+4
    v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

    ---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

    Java Threads: ( => current thread )
      0x5a0b9800 JavaThread "Compiler Source File Reader" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5204, stack(0x5cba0000,0x5cca0000)]
      0x5a0b8c00 JavaThread "Compiler Source File Reader" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=500, stack(0x5caa0000,0x5cba0000)]
      0x5a0b9000 JavaThread "Compiler Source File Reader" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4188, stack(0x5c9a0000,0x5caa0000)]
      0x5a0b8400 JavaThread "[ThreadPool Manager] - Idle Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5580, stack(0x5c8a0000,0x5c9a0000)]
      0x5a0b7000 JavaThread "Worker-7" [_thread_blocked, id=6008, stack(0x5c280000,0x5c380000)]
      0x5a0b6c00 JavaThread "Worker-6" [_thread_blocked, id=5544, stack(0x5c180000,0x5c280000)]
      0x5729dc00 JavaThread "LogCat output receiver for MSM8225QRD5" [_thread_blocked, id=2580, stack(0x5c080000,0x5c180000)]
      0x5729d800 JavaThread "Device Client Monitor" [_thread_in_native, id=3880, stack(0x5b270000,0x5b370000)]
      0x5729f000 JavaThread "Device List Monitor" [_thread_in_native, id=408, stack(0x5bd50000,0x5be50000)]
      0x5729e800 JavaThread "Worker-5" [_thread_blocked, id=4936, stack(0x5b700000,0x5b800000)]
      0x5729e400 JavaThread "Worker-4" [_thread_blocked, id=5612, stack(0x5b400000,0x5b500000)]
      0x5729d000 JavaThread "Monitor" [_thread_in_native, id=5820, stack(0x5b0c0000,0x5b1c0000)]
      0x5729cc00 JavaThread "org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.JavaReconciler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6088, stack(0x5afc0000,0x5b0c0000)]
      0x5729c400 JavaThread "Worker-3" [_thread_blocked, id=3792, stack(0x5aec0000,0x5afc0000)]
      0x5729bc00 JavaThread "Worker-2" [_thread_blocked, id=2780, stack(0x5acc0000,0x5adc0000)]
      0x5729b800 JavaThread "Java indexing" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2596, stack(0x598f0000,0x599f0000)]
      0x5729ac00 JavaThread "Bundle File Closer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5448, stack(0x597f0000,0x598f0000)]
      0x57299000 JavaThread "Worker-1" [_thread_blocked, id=5952, stack(0x59440000,0x59540000)]
      0x5729a400 JavaThread "Worker-0" [_thread_blocked, id=4132, stack(0x58850000,0x58950000)]
      0x5729a000 JavaThread "Worker-JM" [_thread_blocked, id=4288, stack(0x57c50000,0x57d50000)]
      0x57299800 JavaThread "[Timer] - Main Queue Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5376, stack(0x57a80000,0x57b80000)]
      0x57298c00 JavaThread "Framework Event Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4176, stack(0x57880000,0x57980000)]
      0x57298400 JavaThread "Start Level Event Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4920, stack(0x57780000,0x57880000)]
      0x57298000 JavaThread "State Data Manager" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2624, stack(0x57680000,0x57780000)]
      0x57297800 JavaThread "Framework Active Thread" [_thread_blocked, id=5736, stack(0x56c70000,0x56d70000)]
      0x55fa0400 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1484, stack(0x56760000,0x56860000)]
      0x55f9b000 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5660, stack(0x56660000,0x56760000)]
      0x55f9a000 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2636, stack(0x56560000,0x56660000)]
      0x55f97000 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2684, stack(0x56460000,0x56560000)]
      0x55f68000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3900, stack(0x56360000,0x56460000)]
      0x55f62c00 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2364, stack(0x56260000,0x56360000)]
    =>0x01b2c000 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=1840, stack(0x00030000,0x00130000)]

    Other Threads:
      0x55f61800 VMThread [stack: 0x56160000,0x56260000] [id=4236]
      0x55fb9c00 WatcherThread [stack: 0x56860000,0x56960000] [id=2608]

    VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

    VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

    Heap
     def new generation   total 30976K, used 10675K [0x03cb0000, 0x05e40000, 0x13cb0000)
      eden space 27584K,  38% used [0x03cb0000, 0x0471ce60, 0x057a0000)
      from space 3392K,   0% used [0x05af0000, 0x05af0000, 0x05e40000)
      to   space 3392K,   0% used [0x057a0000, 0x057a0000, 0x05af0000)
     tenured generation   total 68604K, used 68604K [0x13cb0000, 0x17faf000, 0x33cb0000)
       the space 68604K, 100% used [0x13cb0000, 0x17faf000, 0x17faf000, 0x17faf000)
     compacting perm gen  total 52736K, used 52679K [0x33cb0000, 0x37030000, 0x53cb0000)
       the space 52736K,  99% used [0x33cb0000, 0x37021e60, 0x37022000, 0x37030000)
    No shared spaces configured.

    Card table byte_map: [0x55ab0000,0x55d40000] byte_map_base: 0x55a91a80

    Polling page: 0x002c0000

    Code Cache  [0x01c30000, 0x024f8000, 0x03c30000)
     total_blobs=4092 nmethods=3852 adapters=171 free_code_cache=23782Kb largest_free_block=24346880

    Compilation events (10 events):
    Event: 60.435 Thread 0x55f9b000 3940             org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.MarkerManager$1MaxSeverityVisitor::visitElement (76 bytes)
    Event: 60.435 Thread 0x55f9b000 nmethod 3940 0x024f7388 code [0x024f7490, 0x024f75ec]
    Event: 60.453 Thread 0x55f9b000 3941             org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.AbstractDataTreeNode::assembleWith (177 bytes)
    Event: 60.458 Thread 0x55f9b000 

    Event: 60.465 Thread 0x55f9b000 3942             org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.NoDataDeltaNode::<init> (7 bytes)
    Event: 60.465 Thread 0x55f9b000 nmethod 3942 0x024f7708 code [0x024f7800, 0x024f78d0]
    Event: 60.466 Thread 0x55f9b000 3943             org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.AbstractDataTreeNode::hasData (2 bytes)
    Event: 60.466 Thread 0x55f9b000 nmethod 3943 0x024f7948 code [0x024f7a40, 0x024f7ac0]
    Event: 60.468 Thread 0x55f9b000 3944             org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.AbstractDataTreeNode::assembleWith (124 bytes)
    Event: 60.474 Thread 0x55f9b000 


    GC Heap History (10 events):
    Event: 50.086 GC heap before
    {Heap before GC invocations=49 (full 12):
     def new generation   total 29440K, used 26176K [0x03cb0000, 0x05ca0000, 0x13cb0000)
      eden space 26176K, 100% used [0x03cb0000, 0x05640000, 0x05640000)
      from space 3264K,   0% used [0x05640000, 0x05640000, 0x05970000)
      to   space 3264K,   0% used [0x05970000, 0x05970000, 0x05ca0000)
     tenured generation   total 65276K, used 58186K [0x13cb0000, 0x17c6f000, 0x33cb0000)
       the space 65276K,  89% used [0x13cb0000, 0x17582970, 0x17582a00, 0x17c6f000)
     compacting perm gen  total 52480K, used 52315K [0x33cb0000, 0x36ff0000, 0x53cb0000)
       the space 52480K,  99% used [0x33cb0000, 0x36fc6d78, 0x36fc6e00, 0x36ff0000)
    No shared spaces configured.
    Event: 50.103 GC heap after
    Heap after GC invocations=50 (full 12):
     def new generation   total 29440K, used 2981K [0x03cb0000, 0x05ca0000, 0x13cb0000)
      eden space 26176K,   0% used [0x03cb0000, 0x03cb0000, 0x05640000)
      from space 3264K,  91% used [0x05970000, 0x05c594c0, 0x05ca0000)
      to   space 3264K,   0% used [0x05640000, 0x05640000, 0x05970000)
     tenured generation   total 65276K, used 58186K [0x13cb0000, 0x17c6f000, 0x33cb0000)
       the space 65276K,  89% used [0x13cb0000, 0x17582970, 0x17582a00, 0x17c6f000)
     compacting perm gen  total 52480K, used 52315K [0x33cb0000, 0x36ff0000, 0x53cb0000)
       the space 52480K,  99% used [0x33cb0000, 0x36fc6d78, 0x36fc6e00, 0x36ff0000)
    No shared spaces configured.
    }
    Event: 51.853 GC heap before
    {Heap before GC invocations=50 (full 12):
     def new generation   total 29440K, used 29157K [0x03cb0000, 0x05ca0000, 0x13cb0000)
      eden space 26176K, 100% used [0x03cb0000, 0x05640000, 0x05640000)
      from space 3264K,  91% used [0x05970000, 0x05c594c0, 0x05ca0000)
      to   space 3264K,   0% used [0x05640000, 0x05640000, 0x05970000)
     tenured generation   total 65276K, used 58186K [0x13cb0000, 0x17c6f000, 0x33cb0000)
       the space 65276K,  89% used [0x13cb0000, 0x17582970, 0x17582a00, 0x17c6f000)
     compacting perm gen  total 52480K, used 52315K [0x33cb0000, 0x36ff0000, 0x53cb0000)
       the space 52480K,  99% used [0x33cb0000, 0x36fc6d88, 0x36fc6e00, 0x36ff0000)
    No shared spaces configured.
    Event: 51.882 GC heap after
    Heap after GC invocations=51 (full 12):
     def new generation   total 29440K, used 3264K [0x03cb0000, 0x05ca0000, 0x13cb0000)
      eden space 26176K,   0% used [0x03cb0000, 0x03cb0000, 0x05640000)
      from space 3264K, 100% used [0x05640000, 0x05970000, 0x05970000)
      to   space 3264K,   0% used [0x05970000, 0x05970000, 0x05ca0000)
     tenured generation   total 65276K, used 62413K [0x13cb0000, 0x17c6f000, 0x33cb0000)
       the space 65276K,  95% used [0x13cb0000, 0x179a35e8, 0x179a3600, 0x17c6f000)
     compacting perm gen  total 52480K, used 52315K [0x33cb0000, 0x36ff0000, 0x53cb0000)
       the space 52480K,  99% used [0x33cb0000, 0x36fc6d88, 0x36fc6e00, 0x36ff0000)
    No shared spaces configured.
    }
    Event: 54.055 GC heap before
    {Heap before GC invocations=51 (full 12):
     def new generation   total 29440K, used 29440K [0x03cb0000, 0x05ca0000, 0x13cb0000)
      eden space 26176K, 100% used [0x03cb0000, 0x05640000, 0x05640000)
      from space 3264K, 100% used [0x05640000, 0x05970000, 0x05970000)
      to   space 3264K,   0% used [0x05970000, 0x05970000, 0x05ca0000)
     tenured generation   total 65276K, used 62413K [0x13cb0000, 0x17c6f000, 0x33cb0000)
       the space 65276K,  95% used [0x13cb0000, 0x179a35e8, 0x179a3600, 0x17c6f000)
     compacting perm gen  total 52480K, used 52315K [0x33cb0000, 0x36ff0000, 0x53cb0000)
       the space 52480K,  99% used [0x33cb0000, 0x36fc6d88, 0x36fc6e00, 0x36ff0000)
    No shared spaces configured.
    Event: 54.466 GC heap after
    Heap after GC invocations=52 (full 13):
     def new generation   total 29888K, used 3224K [0x03cb0000, 0x05d10000, 0x13cb0000)
      eden space 26624K,  12% used [0x03cb0000, 0x03fd6290, 0x056b0000)
      from space 3264K,   0% used [0x056b0000, 0x056b0000, 0x059e0000)
      to   space 3264K,   0% used [0x059e0000, 0x059e0000, 0x05d10000)
     tenured generation   total 66172K, used 66171K [0x13cb0000, 0x17d4f000, 0x33cb0000)
       the space 66172K,  99% used [0x13cb0000, 0x17d4ec48, 0x17d4ee00, 0x17d4f000)
     compacting perm gen  total 52480K, used 52315K [0x33cb0000, 0x36ff0000, 0x53cb0000)
       the space 52480K,  99% used [0x33cb0000, 0x36fc6d88, 0x36fc6e00, 0x36ff0000)
    No shared spaces configured.
    }
    Event: 56.364 GC heap before
    {Heap before GC invocations=52 (full 13):
     def new generation   total 29888K, used 26621K [0x03cb0000, 0x05d10000, 0x13cb0000)
      eden space 26624K,  99% used [0x03cb0000, 0x056af6f8, 0x056b0000)
      from space 3264K,   0% used [0x056b0000, 0x056b0000, 0x059e0000)
      to   space 3264K,   0% used [0x059e0000, 0x059e0000, 0x05d10000)
     tenured generation   total 66172K, used 66171K [0x13cb0000, 0x17d4f000, 0x33cb0000)
       the space 66172K,  99% used [0x13cb0000, 0x17d4ec48, 0x17d4ee00, 0x17d4f000)
     compacting perm gen  total 52736K, used 52480K [0x33cb0000, 0x37030000, 0x53cb0000)
       the space 52736K,  99% used [0x33cb0000, 0x36ff0278, 0x36ff0400, 0x37030000)
    No shared spaces configured.
    Event: 56.880 GC heap after
    Heap after GC invocations=53 (full 14):
     def new generation   total 30976K, used 204K [0x03cb0000, 0x05e40000, 0x13cb0000)
      eden space 27584K,   0% used [0x03cb0000, 0x03ce3238, 0x057a0000)
      from space 3392K,   0% used [0x057a0000, 0x057a0000, 0x05af0000)
      to   space 3392K,   0% used [0x05af0000, 0x05af0000, 0x05e40000)
     tenured generation   total 68604K, used 68603K [0x13cb0000, 0x17faf000, 0x33cb0000)
       the space 68604K,  99% used [0x13cb0000, 0x17faefe8, 0x17faf000, 0x17faf000)
     compacting perm gen  total 52736K, used 52480K [0x33cb0000, 0x37030000, 0x53cb0000)
       the space 52736K,  99% used [0x33cb0000, 0x36ff0278, 0x36ff0400, 0x37030000)
    No shared spaces configured.
    }
    Event: 59.920 GC heap before
    {Heap before GC invocations=53 (full 14):
     def new generation   total 30976K, used 27584K [0x03cb0000, 0x05e40000, 0x13cb0000)
      eden space 27584K, 100% used [0x03cb0000, 0x057a0000, 0x057a0000)
      from space 3392K,   0% used [0x057a0000, 0x057a0000, 0x05af0000)
      to   space 3392K,   0% used [0x05af0000, 0x05af0000, 0x05e40000)
     tenured generation   total 68604K, used 68603K [0x13cb0000, 0x17faf000, 0x33cb0000)
       the space 68604K,  99% used [0x13cb0000, 0x17faefe8, 0x17faf000, 0x17faf000)
     compacting perm gen  total 52736K, used 52511K [0x33cb0000, 0x37030000, 0x53cb0000)
       the space 52736K,  99% used [0x33cb0000, 0x36ff7f28, 0x36ff8000, 0x37030000)
    No shared spaces configured.
    Event: 60.377 GC heap after
    Heap after GC invocations=54 (full 15):
     def new generation   total 30976K, used 211K [0x03cb0000, 0x05e40000, 0x13cb0000)
      eden space 27584K,   0% used [0x03cb0000, 0x03ce4eb0, 0x057a0000)
      from space 3392K,   0% used [0x05af0000, 0x05af0000, 0x05e40000)
      to   space 3392K,   0% used [0x057a0000, 0x057a0000, 0x05af0000)
     tenured generation   total 68604K, used 68604K [0x13cb0000, 0x17faf000, 0x33cb0000)
       the space 68604K, 100% used [0x13cb0000, 0x17faf000, 0x17faf000, 0x17faf000)
     compacting perm gen  total 52736K, used 52511K [0x33cb0000, 0x37030000, 0x53cb0000)
       the space 52736K,  99% used [0x33cb0000, 0x36ff7f28, 0x36ff8000, 0x37030000)
    No shared spaces configured.
    }

    Deoptimization events (0 events):
    No events

    Internal exceptions (10 events):
    Event: 60.425 Thread 0x5729bc00 Threw 0x03d24918 at C:\re\jdk7u51\527\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp:717
    Event: 60.425 Thread 0x5729bc00 Threw 0x03d24bd0 at C:\re\jdk7u51\527\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp:717
    Event: 60.425 Thread 0x5729bc00 Threw 0x03d24e58 at C:\re\jdk7u51\527\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp:717
    Event: 60.425 Thread 0x5729bc00 Threw 0x03d254d0 at C:\re\jdk7u51\527\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp:717
    Event: 60.425 Thread 0x5729bc00 Threw 0x03d25788 at C:\re\jdk7u51\527\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp:717
    Event: 60.425 Thread 0x5729bc00 Threw 0x03d25a10 at C:\re\jdk7u51\527\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp:717
    Event: 60.425 Thread 0x5729bc00 Threw 0x03d25f98 at C:\re\jdk7u51\527\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp:717
    Event: 60.425 Thread 0x5729bc00 Threw 0x03d26250 at C:\re\jdk7u51\527\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp:717
    Event: 60.425 Thread 0x5729bc00 Threw 0x03d264d8 at C:\re\jdk7u51\527\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp:717
    Event: 60.528 Thread 0x5729b800 Threw 0x03fe9808 at C:\re\jdk7u51\527\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\sharedRuntime.cpp:591

    Events (10 events):
    Event: 60.898 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias
    Event: 60.898 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias done
    Event: 60.899 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias
    Event: 60.899 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias done
    Event: 61.027 loading class 0x58504330
    Event: 61.027 loading class 0x58504330 done
    Event: 61.027 loading class 0x58504300
    Event: 61.027 loading class 0x58504300 done
    Event: 61.203 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias
    Event: 61.204 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias done


(..)    
    VM Arguments:
    jvm_args: -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6 -Xms40m -Xmx768m -Declipse.buildId=v22.3.0-887826 -XX:MaxPermSize=512M 
    java_command: <unknown>
    Launcher Type: generic

(...)    


    ---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

    OS: Windows 7 Build 7601 Service Pack 1

    CPU:total 2 (2 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 23 stepping 10, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, tsc

    Memory: 4k page, physical 3109492k(1486288k free), swap 7298916k(5500348k free)

    vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (24.51-b03) for windows-x86 JRE (1.7.0_51-b13), built on Dec 18 2013 19:09:58 by "java_re" with unknown MS VC++:1600

    time: Wed Mar 12 17:53:48 2014
    elapsed time: 90 seconds
```

Comment: what jdk do you have?

Comment: I added versions info to my question.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you clean up your eclipse using terminal

Mine directory

```
cd /Applications/eclipse_juno/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS
```

Clean command

```
./eclipse -clean
```

Or

edit your eclipse.ini

change this line

```
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
```

into this one

```
-Xms768m
-Xmx768m
```

eclipse.ini

```
-startup
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-XX:MaxPermSize=192m
-Xms768m
-Xmx768m
-Xdock:icon=../Resources/Eclipse.icns
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
```

If still happen, restart your machine. I suggest you upgrade your RAM up to 8gb.

Comment: Cleaning didn't help. Or more precisely eclipse didn't crashed just after running but few minutes later when I tried to open one of layouts.

Comment: It's much cheaper to return to the older version of Eclipse than to add more ram.... but thanks for help...

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse crashes in SWT code which is native code inside Eclipse, so verify if you are running a supported combination of Windows version, Java version and Eclipse version. If not, change the component not working.

The page for Eclipse 4.3 is https://www.eclipse.org/projects/project-plan.php?projectid=eclipse#target_environments

Comment: I added version info to my question. It seems that Java is newer than required but it seems not to be the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I am also facing almost the same problem and I've created a question for my problem.
But have you tried with the following solutions?

[Eclipse ADT crash when autocomplete popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20733572/eclipse-adt-crash-when-autocomplete-popup/22353909#22353909)

[Eclipse ADT Bundle crashes suddenly on Mint 16 Petra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21634846/eclipse-adt-bundle-crashes-suddenly-on-mint-16-petra)

[Eclipse continue crashing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20203771/eclipse-continue-crash)

In summery in those solution it is said to add some configuration in eclipse.ini file like
add the following line at the end of your eclipse.ini file.
That solution worked for many people but not for me.

```
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
```

Though those given solution didn't worked for me but those can help you.

If you solve your problem then please let me know the solution. Here I am giving the link of my question.

[Eclipse in adt-bundle for android development freezes by auto complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22357462/eclipse-in-adt-bundle-for-android-development-freezes-by-auto-complete)

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for that help. However as I spent so much time trying to solve the problem and I didnt find the reason, finally I installed the old version of Eclipse/Android sdk (I still have impression it can be somehow related with memory requirements as my computer has only 4GB and win 7 32 bit, so in practice only a bit more thant 3GB is available).

Answer (score 0):

I have had a lot of problems with autocomplete function crashing my eclipse session from time to time.
I reported a bug: [Eclipse Bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/buglist.cgi?f1=reporter&list_id=18667472&o1=equals&resolution=---&v1=%25user%25)

... and later on I detected that disabling some "proposal kinds" works for me (s. screenshot)
[image]